# Extract All Characters after last occurrence of a pattern C#

Tags: c#, string

The strings are of the following pattern

```
1.0.0.0
1.0.0.1
1.0.0.2
...
...
...
```

I am looking for a code which will read the last created string and increment the last numeral by 1 and save it as a new string.

How do I do it?

Best Regards,

Magic

Comment: Is that one string or a list of strings?

Comment: List of strings. The last created string will the one where the last digit is largest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can split the string into the components, parse the last one so that you can increase it, and put them together again:

```
string[] parts = version.Split('.');
parts[3] = (Int32.Parse(parts[3]) + 1).ToString();
version = String.Join(".", parts);
```

Another method that may be slightly more efficient is to get only the last component using string operations:

```
int pos = version.LastIndexOf('.') + 1;
int num = Int32.Parse(version.Substring(pos));
version = version.Substring(0, pos) + num.ToString();
```

Answer (score 10):

If your intention is to always get the last substring after a specific character (excluding the delimiter character of course (in this case a period)), which I believe is your intention:

Keep it simple with a 1 liner:

```
string myLastSubString = myStringToParse.Split('.').Last();
```

I'll let the other posts answer the rest of your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
public string DoMagic(string s)
{
    string t = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ')+1);
    return t.Substring(0, t.Length-1) + (int.Parse(t[t.Length-1].ToString())+1).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format will not change, this may be your best solution. This will work even with unordered version list strings.

```
        string VersionList = "1.0.0.0 1.0.0.1 1.0.0.2";

        List<Version> Versions = new List<Version>();

        foreach (string FlatVersion in VersionList.Split(' '))
            Versions.Add(new Version(FlatVersion));

        Versions.Sort(); Versions.Reverse();

        Version MaximumVersion = Versions[0];

        Version NewVersion = new Version(
            MaximumVersion.Major, 
            MaximumVersion.MajorRevision,
            MaximumVersion.Minor,
            MaximumVersion.MinorRevision + 1);
```

Comment: This is a good solution. If any of the strings contains an extra dot, or a non numeric character, this will fail. But if all the strings are in a correct format, it will work very well.

Comment: I wouldn't do Versions.Reverse() though - it's a waste of cpu. Simple Version maxVersion = Versions[Versions.Count - 1];

Comment: True. Both List(T).Item and List(T).Count() are O(1). List.Reverse() is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string list is:

```
List<string> stringList;
```

You could obtain the last entry in that list using:

```
string lastString = stringList[stringList.Length - 1];
```

Then get the last character of that string using:

```
char c = lastString[lastString.Length - 1];
```

Convert and increment the char into a decimal:

```
int newNum = Int32.Parse(c.ToString()) + 1;
```

Finally, copy the original string and replace the last number with the new one:

```
string finalString = lastString;
finalString[finalString.Length - 1] = c;
```

Now add this back to the original list:

```
stringList.Add(finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that only the last element in the sub strings vary:

```
List<string> items = GetItems();
string[] max = input.Split(' ').Max().Split('.');
string next = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", max[0], max[1], max[2], int.Parse(max[3]) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VB right now, but the translation to C# should be straightforward. From here implementing your actual problem should be straightforward - you have a collection, the last item is the last number, just increment it and replace the last item of the collection and write it out again.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim matchC As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches("111.222.333", "\d+")
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        For Each x In matchC
            Console.Write(i.ToString & " ")
            Console.WriteLine(x)
            i = i + 1
        Next
        ' remember to check the case where no matches occur in your real code.
        Console.WriteLine("last number is " & matchC.Item(matchC.Count - 1).ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```