# Regex match with multiple occurrences

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, regex-negation

With strings that look like for example

```
90001:21880004:los angeles
10001:21880005:new york
```

I want to extract the city names at the end through a regex. I am finding this hard to do with the two `:` can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A variation of the answer here will work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153630/extract-all-characters-after-last-occurrence-of-a-pattern-c-sharp. Use ':' instead of '.', and `parts[2]` instead of `parts[3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use regex:

`^\d+:\d+:(.+)$` should work.

`([^\d:]+)` should also work.

However, it really just looks like you want to do a Split.

`"11111:111111:name".Split(':')[2]` is likely your fastest method.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can probably use a regular expression like:

```
(\d+:)+([A-Za-z\s]+)
```

Where you could capture the numbered groups `(\d+:)+`
And then the text `([A-Za-z\s])` Would capture most names of cities.

That is the basic gist of it at least.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Regex for this, you can use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string line = "90001:21880004:los angeles";
string cityName = line.Split(':')[2]; // Gives 'los angeles'
```

This will split the string in three parts (because you have two `:`s) and take the third one (Remember that Arrays are 0-based), which contains your city name.

Just be sure no city from your dataset contains a `:` in their name.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without `Regex`:

```
string la = "90001:21880004:los angeles".Split(':')[2];
string ny = "10001:21880005:new york".Split(':')[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are exactly **2** colons you could do something like this:

```
\d:\d:([a-zA-Z\s]+)
```

by not adding parentheses around the numbers they won't get captured by the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another regex

```
string pattern = @"[^:]+";
var city = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```